# What exactly is the 'continuous asset price model'?

Tags: asset-pricing, lognormal, continuous-time

I am reading *An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation* by Higham. In Chapter 6, the book covers two asset price models, a discrete one and a continuous one. In Section 6.3 (Continuous asset model) he "derives" the model using mostly heuristics.

After having read it, I am not sure what are the assumptions here. I.e., the question is: **What is exactly the continuous asset model?** I.e., **what are the underlying assumptions**?

Note: I am *not* talking about "assumptions" such as 'volatility is constant' -- I mean mathematical assumptions.

Is it true that essentially the **only** things assumed are that

(1) $\log \left( \frac{S(t_2)}{S(t_1)} \right)  \sim \text{Normal} \left( (\mu - \frac12 \sigma^2 )(t_2-t_1) , \sigma^2 (t_2-t_1)\right)$  (for all $t_2 > t_1$), and

(2)   $\log \left( \frac{S(t_2)}{S(t_1)} \right) $ and $\log \left( \frac{S(t_3)}{S(t_2)} \right) $ are independent, for all $t_3>t_2>t_2$?

Thank you.

Comment: In a discrete model time is indexed by integers t=0,1,2,... and prices are chosen from a discrete grid such as ...,15,16,17,18,... The Price "jumps" from one allowed value to another. In a continuous model time is is a Real number and Prices also can take on any Real value. The price funstion is assumed to be continuous or RCLL.

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't help at all. You did not answer any question.

Comment: (1) It is a comment not an answer. (2) That book (which I don't have) is very quirky in its presentation. You should consider reading a more standard treatment of the subject. (3) Another thing that must be assumed (other than the 2 you mention), is how $S(t_0)$ is determined (the initial value). That's it, the 3 assumptions: starting point, distribution of increments, independent increments assumption.